# How can I scrape any website using scrapy in such a way that the website doesn't considers my bot as a registered or logged in user?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

The website is considering my bot as a logged in user but i want to make the website identify my bot as an unregistered user.

Comment: Clear your browser Cache nad cookies

Comment: Have already tried this. But It's not working. Actually I'm getting the same result if I'm running the crawl on localhost too.

Comment: Then you definitely passing credentials in your code. Post your code

Comment: What makes you think you are considered a logged in user in the first place?